# find occurrences of elements of a list in a list of list

Tags: python, list, set

i have a list `[1, 2, 3]`

i want to find number of times the elements of this list appears in a list of list:

```
lol = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 6, 7, 1], [1, 4, 2, 6, 3]]

occurrences = 4
```

What I’m doing currently is the following:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
lol = [[1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 6, 7, 1], [1, 4, 2, 6, 3]]

def get_count(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    return sum([a.issubset(x) for x in b])

print(get_count(a, lol))
```

This method works but is quite slow when I have 100s of 1000s of list to compare with a list of list (`lol` remains static!)

can we also preserve the "order" of the elements? there can be other elements in between. in this case `occurrences` will be 2 for the above case

Comment: Two micro-optimizations: (1) `lol` to a list of sets outside the function call.  I believe that Python will otherwise convert each `x` from list to set with each call of `get_count()`.  (2) `sum()` can take a generator expression: `sum(a <= x for x in b)`.

Comment: your search for occurrences will really slow down your function

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
testlist = lol                  ##Create a test list that we will work with

for i in range len(testlist):   ##Start a loop that will repeat length of testlist times
    if a in testlist:           ##If/When it finds the first occurrence of the list a
        Occurrences =+ 1         ##It adds 1 to the amount off occurences
        Pos = testlist.index(a)
        testlist.del(Pos)       ##It deletes the instance from the list.
```

This should work